# Changing "abroad on permanent accommodation" to sound better

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Is it correct to say "to go abroad on permanent accommodation"? It doesn't sound right to me. What's the right way to say that?

My pupil has written "some people go abroad on permanent accommodation". I assume he means that the people don't come back to their home country but become residents of other countries.

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to say. (In other words, I'm having trouble understanding your question. Could you please clarify?)

Comment: Right, I agree with Martha.  Could you clarify what _accomodation_ means in your question title?

Comment: My pupil has written: "some people go abroad on permanent accomodation". I assume, he means that the people don't come back to their home country but become residents of other countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have certainly heard *go abroad on permanent vacation*. Is that what you meant to say? Someone on permanent vacation is most likely living large on an island, enjoying vast sums of wealth away from prying eyes. *Going [abroad] on permanent vacation* may also be used as a euphemism for *emigrating*.

Answer (score 4):

"settle abroad" is also quite a popular phrase.

Answer (score 3):

To move to another country permanently is "to emigrate" eg. "I'm emigrating to Australia"

Comment: +1; "Emigrate" also has some implications with regards to citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a little trouble understanding the meaning but I would try:

> I am living abroad.
>
> I will be living abroad.
>
> I am about to live abroad.

Comment: These three options don't have the feeling of permanence associated with them.

Comment: @apoorv: "Living" is more commonly associated with "this is where I will be living until further notice." Other examples: _He is living with his parents_; _I live with my spouse_; _I live in Texas_; _I will be living in Canada_.

Comment: But abroad is rooted to your home country, contrasting with the meaning of "live" which carries a sense of permanence. So I tend to view it as you are "living abroad for the foreseeable future, but will be back".

Comment: I guess I respectfully disagree. The differences between what you see and what I see are too nuanced to go at it in the comments. In my opinion, "live" works just fine.